# Insert or update mysql table

Tags: mysql, replace, insert

Hy All. I have some code that create queries and i'm updating database. But it delete all table and reinsert the same code. What i want is to update if is necessary or to insert if doesn't exist.

What i've tried is this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (data, fk_product, fk_entrepot ,value, price, type_mouvement, tip_act, nr_act , id_act, id_linie_act, motiv) VALUES   
 ('2010-06-14', '64', '1', '1', '4.46', '2',  'BC', '1', '7', '16', 'BC/1/14-06-2010') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
fk_product = VALUES(fk_product),
fk_entrepot = VALUES(fk_entrepot);


REPLACE INTO mytable SET data = '2010-06-14', fk_product = '64', fk_entrepot = '1', value = '1', price = '4.46', type_mouvement = '2',  tip_act = 'BC', nr_act = '1', id_act = '7',id_linie_act = '16', motiv = 'BC/1/14-06-2010';
```

rowid is PRIMARY
fk_product Foreign Key
fk_entrepot Foreign Key

Thank you in advance for implication

Comment: Which programing language you are using

Comment: Sorry. I'm using php

Answer (score 0):

```
 First fire select query with all values you are inserting then check

 then check $num = mysql_num_rows() whether that record exists then check  

 if  else condition like

    if($num >0)
      {
       echo "fire your update query here";
      }
    else
     {
     echo "fire insert query";
    }
```